# Xcode UI Testing: Can I use UI Testing scripts to access the target app folder?

Tags: ios, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

When I create UI Testing scripts, I meet a problem. 
I need to access log file which is created under target APP document folder. 
However, the UI Testing APP is running as another thread.

```
 NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

This method can only return the path of UI Testing APP document rather than target app.

Is there a way to access the folder of target app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your application is sand boxed you can't access the document directory of that application. Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW1

If you want that file to be tested. create that file in test project also and check.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kindly response. That would be a little sad. If the test target is Unit Test, it would get the directory. However, for UI Testing, it seems run as another app. :(

Comment: @June - I'd recommend you file a Feature Request radar to Apple. That way they can be aware that there's a limitation in their design that developers need.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [short blog post](https://medium.com/@robnash_65403/installing-data-during-uitests-df250290cf4a) about this.

A short-term solution for me was to create a UITextField that the user wasn't aware of. The UITesting target would interact with the textField and type a code, as part of the UITest.

Once any given UITest started running, the first interaction was with the text field. The text field would become the first responder (using the accessibility tag), which lead to the keyboard sliding onscreen.

The test would then proceed to interact with the keyboard and type a string, before hitting the 'return' key, on the keyboard. The keyboard dismissed and the string was sent to the UITextFieldDelegate.

The string represented a filename. I set up a system of codes that corresponded to .zip files I had stashed away. Each code that was typed by the various tests, corresponded to zip files that contained a version of the data I needed in the docs dir.

So it was just a case of unpacking the data and writing it to the docs folder before the UITest continued.

I have sent a feature request to Apple for access to the candidate app doc dir via the UITest target.